# Cant access to a pointer-vector map element,

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, vector

into my private section I have :

```
vector<  vector<map<unsigned short int,col_data> > *> buffer_vectorS;
vector< map<unsigned short int,col_data> > * buffer_current;
map<unsigned short int,col_data> buffer_current_map;
```

( coldata is a simple structure: int, int, int, double )

Later I create a vector of map data, and save its pointer

```
vector<map<unsigned short int,col_data> > * buffer_vector = new vector<map<unsigned short int,col_data> >;
buffer_vectorS.push_back(buffer_vector);
buffer_current = buffer_vector;
```

Later I'd want to use the map element of the buffer_current to get-store data,

```
buffer_current_map = &buffer_current[index];
```

But this last does not compile.... I dont know how to write it...
How can I access to an item of buffer_current?
Can you help me ?

Comment: Why do you need the reference operator (`&`) ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
buffer_current_map = (*buffer_vector)[index];
```

Be warned though, that will perform a copy operation on the map. You might want to access the map using pointer semantics:

```
map<unsigned short int,col_data> *buffer_current_map;
buffer_current_map = &(*buffer_vector)[index];
```

Then no copy will be done. Although, the pointer might be invalidated if a resize is done on the vector.